# Link calling a jQuery function doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a jQuery newb so this is probably rudimentary.

I have a test page here: http://www.problemio.com where I am trying to make links to vote up or down.

Here is how the links look like:

```
<a class="link_button" id="vote_up">Vote Up</a> 
<a class="link_button" id="vote_down">Vote Down</a>
```

I use the class attribute for styling all over the site with that link_button so I decided to use the id attribute to distinguish the link for the jQuery call.

Here is how my jQuery function looks like:

```
$('a.vote_up').click(function() 
{
alert("up");
});
```

Right now I just want to make sure it is getting called properly. But the alert isn't getting called which is making me think this is broken somewhere.  Any idea how I can get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using the class selector `.` instead of the id selector `#`. Hence do either

```
$('#vote_up').click(function(){
     alert("up");
});
```

or

```
$('.link_button').click(function(){ 
    if( this.id === 'vote_up' )
        alert('vote up'); 
    else if ( this.id === 'vote_down' )
        alert('vote down'); 
 }
```

EDIT: also make sure everything is in a $(document).ready... i.e

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#vote_up').click(function(){
         alert("up");
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually I just made the change to $('#vote_up').click(function(){ and it is still not working.  Any idea why that may be?

Answer (score 5):

Your current selector is incorrect, it is looking for an `a` tag with a **class** of `vote_up` not it's id...

use this instead...

```
$(function() {
    $('#vote_up')...
});
```

Comment: Just made that change and it is still not doing that alert.  Any idea why that may be?

Comment: @Genadinik see update, just need to make sure the DOM is loaded before attaching event handlers...

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the id selector?

```
$('#vote_up').click(function() {
    alert('up');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`a.vote_up` looks for an `<a>` tag with the class `vote_up`.  In your HTML `vote_up` is an ID, so you want this:

```
$('#vote_up').click(function()
```

Comment: Just made that change and it is still not doing that alert. Any idea why that may be?